# Custom Product attribute is not displaying while adding configurable product in Create New Attribute?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have created attribute successfully using script. 
It is displayed in Stores -> Product and assigned the custom attribute to product.
Now I want to display that custom attribute in Create New Attribute in configurable product?

[image]

Comment: What value for Catalog Input Type for Store Owner did you set to the new attribute?

Comment: Double check also the Product Variation Attribute Requirements http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html

Comment: @Nikolas I changed Catalog Input Type to dropdown. Still not coming on configurable product.

Comment: catalog_product_attribute also reindexed?

Comment: @Nikolas - I have also reindexed still no effect.

Comment: maybe you also post the attribute code creation from your script?

Comment: Did you also add the attribute to the product's attribute set?

Comment: @nikolas I have assigned attribute to product's attribute set also